# How to convert hourly measured GPP from µmol m-2 s-1 to daily data with unit of gC/m2/day?

Tags: climate-models, co2, greenhouse-gases

I have hourly-observed gross primary production data with the unit as µmol m<sup>-2</sup> s<sup>-1</sup>, how can I convert it to daily data with unit of gC/m<sup>2</sup>/day?
The data is like this:

```
2011-01-01 02:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-01 05:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-01 06:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-01 07:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-01 08:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-01 10:00:00   -0.019085
2011-01-01 13:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-01 15:00:00        -0.0
```

I guess I need to convert µmol to mol by dividing 10<sup>6</sup>, then multiply by the molecular weight of carbon (12). After that, I need to convert the s<sup>-1</sup> to per day by multiplying 3600*24, but do I need to sum over all data in 2011-01-01 or take the mean value because GPP is a flux data?